# how to remove row and add css class when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/enq0kfqL/2/

how to write the remove function and how to add a css class to a row which is clicked .

1.when i click remove the clicked row should get removed

2. when i click the row - row should get highlightrow css class attached
3. also have  to check if the table has any rows or not and put it in a var
4. at a time only one row should be in red (clicked row) if no row is selected the remove button should not be visible

   HTML

   col1header
     
     
       col2header

CSS

```
.visibilityHide {
    visibility: hidden;

}
.highlightRow{
  color:red;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS or Jquery

```
function add()
{var addRow1;
 var addRow2;
addRow1 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow1" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow1" + "</td></tr>";
addRow2 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow2" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow2" + "</td></tr>";
                $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow1);
                 $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow2);

}


function remove()
{

}

function getdetails(row)
{
$('#removerow').css('visibility', 'visible');

}
```

Comment: we can use jquery too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Do it like below (All solutions what you asked for):-***

```js
function add(){
  var addRow1;
  var addRow2;
  addRow1 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow1" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow1" + "</td></tr>";
  addRow2 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow2" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow2" + "</td></tr>";
  $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow1);
  $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow2);
}


function remove(){
  var index = parseInt($('.removeClass').index())+1;
  $('.removeClass').remove(); //remove clicked row
  $('.removed_row').html("<strong>row number "+index+ " removed</strong>");
  if($('table tbody tr').length <=0){
    $('#removerow').hide();
  }
}

function getdetails(row){
  $('#removerow').css('display', 'block');
  $('.removeClass').removeClass('removeClass');
  $(row).addClass('removeClass'); //add class on clicked row
}
```

```css
.visibilityHide {
  display: none;
}
.highlightRow{
  color:red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/* styling for added class so that it looks something different when class added */
.removeClass{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTableid">
<thead>
  <th>
    col1header
  </th>
  <th>
    col2header
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id ="addrows" value="add" onclick="add()" />
<input type="button" id="removerow" value="remove" onclick="remove()" class="visibilityHide" />

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="removed_row"></div>
```

Comment: @tripathy  check the solution now. Everything what you asked is added and working now

Comment: if i delete all rows , and add again - remove button does not appear again

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated javascript code. This will meet all your requirements.

```
function add()
{
    var addRow1;
    var addRow2;
    addRow1 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow1" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow1" + "</td></tr>";
    addRow2 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow2" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow2" + "</td></tr>";
    $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow1);
    $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow2);

}


function remove()
{
    $(".highlightRow").remove();
    $('#removerow').addClass('visibilityHide');
    $("#dropDown").prop("disabled", $("#myTableid tbody tr").length > 0);
}

function getdetails(row)
{
    $('#removerow').toggleClass('visibilityHide', $("#myTableid tbody tr").length === 0);
    $(".highlightRow").removeClass("highlightRow");
    $(row).addClass("highlightRow");
}
```

Comment: this is superb . one request , while removing can you please put a logic like if its last row , i have to make dropdown enable again  $("#dropDown").prop("disabled", false);

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. if it'll work

```js
function add(){
  var addRow1;
  var addRow2;
  addRow1 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow1" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow1" + "</td></tr>";
  addRow2 = "<tr onclick="+"getdetails(this)"+"><td>" + "col1valuerow2" + "</td><td>" + "col2valuerow2" + "</td></tr>";
  $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow1);
  $("#myTableid tbody").append(addRow2);
}


function remove(){
  $('.removeClass').remove(); //remove clicked row
  if($('table tbody tr').length <=0){
    $('#removerow').hide();
  }
  if($('table tbody tr').length===0) {
    alert('This last child has been removed');
    $("#dropDown").prop("disabled", false);
  }
}

function getdetails(row){
  $('#removerow').show();
  $(row).addClass('removeClass'); //add class on clicked row
}
```

```css
.highlightRow{
  color:red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/* styling for added class so that it looks something different when class added */
.removeClass{
  color:red;
}
#removerow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTableid">
<thead>
  <th>
    col1header
  </th>
  <th>
    col2header
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id ="addrows" value="add" onclick="add()" />
<input type="button" id="removerow" value="remove" onclick="remove()" class="visibilityHide" />
```

Checking if the row is the last one is this part of the code

```
if($('table tbody tr').length==0) {
    alert('This last child has been removed');
    $("#dropDown").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: last row check should nt be checked when clicking on row , situation can be like user clicked on  the row but does not remove it , still the dropdown will be enabled . can it be on the remove method , when remvoing , if it see that its removing the last row , it should enable the dropdown

Comment: @tripathy so do you want to disable the remove for the last row and enable the dropdown?

Comment: no  , its like when the last row gets removed , then only dropdown should get enabled , otherwise it should not get enabled

Comment: @tripathy i edited the code so that if you removed the last row the `if` would be triggered

Comment: @tripathy whoops my bad, edited the code so the remove button reappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the answer in my update:

```
function remove()
{
window.selectedRow.remove();
$('#removerow').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function getdetails(row)
{
removeHighlights();
window.selectedRow = row;
row.classList.add("highlightRow");
$('#removerow').css('visibility', 'visible');

}

function removeHighlights() {
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("highlightRow");
while(elements.length > 0){
    elements[0].classList.remove('highlightRow');
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g63zpuuz/

Comment: awsum , but one catch , its saying while removing obejct does not support remove method

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your idea. Can you explain more?